# Regex matches some bracket bullet point

Tags: regex

I want to have a regex matches below:

> (1)hello(2)world

I want to loop for 2 matches, one is (1)hello and the other is (2)world
for each match, (1) is the first group "hello" is the 2nd one

I tried `(\(\d+\))(.*?)` but failed.

Comment: Could you please precise the environment/regex flavor? What is the code you use the regex with? BTW, in most cases, you may just split with `(?=\(\d+\))`, or do you need to have 2 capture groups by all means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use *matching* approach to have access to the `(n)` and `hello` values separately, you need to use a regex like

```
(\(\d+\))([^(]*(?:\((?!\d+\))[^(]*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yCphOf/1). The pattern above is an unrolled equivalent of `(?s)(\(\d+\))((?:(?!\(\d+\)).)*)`.

**Details**:

- `(\(\d+\))`  - Capturing group 1: `(`, 1+ digits, `)`
- `([^(]*(?:\((?!\d+\))[^(]*)*)` -  Capturing group 2:

  - `[^(]*` - 0+ chars other than `(`
  - `(?:\((?!\d+\))[^(]*)*` - zero or more sequences of:

    - `\((?!\d+\))` - a literal `(` not followed with 1+ digits and `)`
    - `[^(]*` - 0+ chars other than `(`.

Comment: hi how did you capture multiple matches like looping??

Comment: @AbdulHameed: Sorry, I do not get the *capture multiple matches like looping* part. Is there anything unclear in my pattern explanation? Please let me know so that I could clarify.

Comment: I saw from this link http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html#spawn_groups that we cant auto generate capture groups.. but yours is able to do it. that's what i want to know how..

Comment: There is no way to "generate" capturing groups, they can only be defined when the pattern are written. My regex only contains 2 capturing groups, and that is exactly what we get upon each match (a match, Group 1 with the parenthesized digits, and Group 2 that contains text up to the next parenthesized digits or end of string).

Comment: oh i got it now.. i misunderstood match and group as same.. thx for the clarification @Wiktor